# How to efficiently package email templates into 2GP

Tags: managed-package, email-template, package-install, 2gp

**What is the best way to package email templates into managed packages, and allow to use them by admin (not necessarily by the one that installed the package) just after installing it?**

I was thinking about using **Lightning Email Templates** or **Classic Email Templates** but `EmailTemplate` object is being shared via Folders and:

1. We cannot package email templates inside Public folders
2. The sharing mechanism allows sharing folders only to users and public groups.

Because of the above, I don't see a possibility to give admin access after installing the package.

Of course, we can use Custom Metadata here, but I would like to use Email Templates in Apex with Template Id to simplify the **merge fields population**.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Won't the admin have a `View All Data` setting, and therefore not be affected by sharing? We package classic email templates in a folder and none of our customers have experienced problems with this...

Comment: Hey @PhilW, the problem here would be that there can be some non Admin users that should have access too (these users have some special permission set assigned). So still there is a way that admin after installing will be able to grant access to these folders?